# imgui-java + Java = UnsatisfiedLinkError(libglfw.so)

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am catching an error when I try to compile the template application from [imgui-java](https://github.com/SpaiR/imgui-java) library using gradle.

**Main.java**

```java
import imgui.ImGui;
import imgui.app.Application;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void configure(Configuration config) {
        config.setTitle("Dear ImGui is Awesome!");
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        ImGui.text("Hello, World!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(new Main());
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to dynamically load library: /tmp/lwjglbuwnertys/3.2.3-SNAPSHOT/libglfw.so(error = null)
        at org.lwjgl.system.linux.LinuxLibrary.loadLibrary(LinuxLibrary.java:32)
        at org.lwjgl.system.linux.LinuxLibrary.<init>(LinuxLibrary.java:19)
        at org.lwjgl.system.APIUtil.apiCreateLibrary(APIUtil.java:123)
        at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNative(Library.java:360)
        at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNativeFromLibraryPath(Library.java:349)
        at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNative(Library.java:264)
        at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNative(Library.java:222)
        at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:674)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1042)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:186)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1105)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1086)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:594)
        at org.lwjgl.system.APIUtil.apiClassTokens(APIUtil.java:348)
        at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback$1.<init>(GLFWErrorCallback.java:98)
        at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(GLFWErrorCallback.java:97)
        at imgui.app.Window.initWindow(Window.java:70)
        at imgui.app.Window.init(Window.java:48)
        at imgui.app.Application.initialize(Application.java:91)
        at imgui.app.Application.launch(Application.java:81)
        at Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'                                                                                                                                                   
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre'

    String imgui_java_version = '1.84.1.0'    
    implementation "io.github.spair:imgui-java-app:$imgui_java_version"
}

application {
    mainClass = 'Main'
}
```

Creater of this library [say](https://github.com/SpaiR/imgui-java/blob/master/README.md#application):

> So you only need one dependency line or one jar in classpath to make
> everything to work. You don't need to add separate dependencies to
> LWJGL or native libraries, since they are already included.

So I can't understand, why do I have a problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: did you put the native lib mentioned in the error message at that place the error message states? if not, did you try to set the system property `java.library.path` to include the folder where the library is stored?

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the version of `imgui-java` you're using, on how you actually installed it, maybe on your OS...

My advice: have a look at [the project issues](https://github.com/SpaiR/imgui-java/issues?q=UnsatisfiedLinkError). Many users seem to have had similar `UnsatisfiedLinkError` issues.

In case you're not familiar with Java: `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is the error you get when Java is trying to load some native library to interact with.

In your case, the missing library is `/tmp/lwjglbuwnertys/3.2.3-SNAPSHOT/libglfw.so`.

Maybe you could check if it is present at this location? Maybe it is present with another name (something like `libimgui-java64.so` instead)? If it is the case, try to rename the library.